# Please add an option to search for posts < X votes in search

Tags: feature-request, search

I'm sometimes looking for very low scored answers/question in order to  find some VERY LOW QUALITY ones.

However, I can't do this with internal search. Why? Beacuse there are only 100 pages available in case there are more than 5000 search results.

If I fill "votes:-15" into internal search box, and I sort it by votes, the latest available post has 60 upvotes.

Can "search for posts with less than X score" be implemented, as opposite for already implemented special phrase `votes:` or at least deleted limit of pages ?

Comment: As an addendum, it would be even better if you could search for scores <=, >=, or within a range (5 <= score <= 10).

Answer (score 4):

I agree that it would be nice to add votes to Stack Overflow's search engine, but I don't think that it's really necessary. Why not just use the following Data Explorer queries?

- [Lowest-Voted Questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1894/lowest-voted-questions?Threshold=-15)
- [Lowest-Voted Answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1895/lowest-voted-answers?Threshold=-15)

Comment: Because data explorer queries hit months old data and aren't discoverable by most people...