# Can I search for questions with "less than" X votes?

Tags: support, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add an option to search for posts < X votes in search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107293/please-add-an-option-to-search-for-posts-x-votes-in-search)

I can search Votes:1 to find only questions with a score of 1 or more, but is there any way (barring Data.SE) I can search for posts *below* a given score? Something like `votes<0 closed:0 deleted:0` ordered by date would be great to find old, close-worthy posts which slipped through the cracks.

Comment: No, but there's an [ancient feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19659/search-filters-by-minimum-rep-maximum-views-maximum-answers-etc). Also [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions), but I imagine that falls into the Data.SE category.